# How can I sort floating-point values in numeric order when they're stored in an nvarchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are the result of a query I ran:

```
10
10.5
11
11.5
12
12.5
13
5
5.5
6
6.5
7
7.5
8
9.5
8.5
9
```

Column's datatype is `nvarchar`.

How can I order by the results?

I tried `Order by asc` and `desc` but did nothing.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in an `nvarchar` column? Fix that and it will `ORDER` correctly.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: its a name of a product and by default this field is string, I cant change that

Answer (score 7):

Use `CAST` to treat the values as numbers:

```
ORDER BY CAST(columnName AS FLOAT)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alphabetical sorting is different than numeric sorting. Cast your column to a float or real.

```
select cast(your_column as float) float_col
from your_table
order by float_col;
```

Ideally, though, you should either

- store floating-point values in a column of type float or real, or
- use an exact numeric type that supports decimals (type numeric or type decimal).

It's not clear from your question whether your application is better off with a float or with an exact numeric.

Answer (score 2):

using varchar you cannot... because it will order it alphabetically..

That is `11` will come befor `7`. And even `101` will come before `77`.

Better take `float` as datatype.